# Balance multi line UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, line-breaks

When I create a `UILabel` with `textAlignement` set to `NSTextAlignmentCenter`, `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and a long text, it splits like this :

```
+------------------------------------+
| Text that does not fit on a single |
|                line                |
+------------------------------------+
```

But what I really want is something like this :

```
+------------------------------------+
|       Text that does not fit       |
|          on a single line          |
+------------------------------------+
```

Of course, I **don't** want to handle the line break manually. I want the label to automatically balance the lines so their lengths are as close as possible.

Comment: Why can't you just make the label smaller?

Comment: Because I don't know beforehand what amount of text will be set to the label. It may fit on a single line, it may not, it may need to reduce the font size because even two line are not enough, etc.

Comment: Handling the line breaks manually is probably what you're going to have to do. Of course, you could create a label subclass that handles it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and inspired by this question I found a solution by just overriding
`- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect`

You can see it in [this GitHub Project](https://github.com/Julioacarrettoni/DEVJACAutoBalancedLabel)

The method itself if you just want to copy / read it is [here](https://github.com/Julioacarrettoni/DEVJACAutoBalancedLabel/blob/master/DEVJACAutoBalancedLabel/DEVJACAutoBalancedLabel.m)

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.textAlignment == NSTextAlignmentCenter) {
        CGRect oneLineRect = [self textRectForBounds:CGRectInfinite limitedToNumberOfLines:1];
        NSInteger numberOfLines = ceil(oneLineRect.size.width / self.bounds.size.width);
        CGFloat betterWidth = (oneLineRect.size.width / numberOfLines);
        if (betterWidth < rect.size.width) {
            CGRect check = CGRectZero;
            do {
                betterWidth *= 1.1;
                CGRect b = CGRectMake(0, 0, betterWidth, CGRectInfinite.size.height);
                check = [self textRectForBounds:b limitedToNumberOfLines:0];
            } while (check.size.height > rect.size.height && betterWidth < rect.size.width);

            if (betterWidth < rect.size.width) {
                CGFloat difference = rect.size.width - betterWidth;
                rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + difference/2.0, rect.origin.y, betterWidth, rect.size.height);
            }
        }
    }
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

PR, forks, comments are welcome!

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your solution, looks like it's working great ! I would accept the answer as it fully solves the problem, but answers that only provide a link are not recommended (your second link is already a dead link, you see how the answer could be useless if the first one died too). Could you paste the useful part of the code directly in your answer ?

Comment: *FACEPALM*
I'm an idiot! I'll update my answer, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4):

I'm working in Swift 3 (iOS 10), so I converted  [dev_jac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027601/dev-jac)'s answer for those who need it:

```
override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    var newRect = rect

    if (textAlignment == .center) {
        let oneLineRect = self.textRect(forBounds: CGRect.infinite, limitedToNumberOfLines: 1)
        let numLines = ceil(oneLineRect.size.width / self.bounds.size.width)
        var betterWidth : CGFloat = oneLineRect.size.width / numLines
        if (betterWidth < rect.size.width) {
            var check = CGRect.zero
            repeat {
                betterWidth *= 1.1
                let b = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: betterWidth, height: CGRect.infinite.size.height)
                check = self.textRect(forBounds: b, limitedToNumberOfLines: 0)
            } while (check.size.height > rect.size.height && betterWidth < rect.size.width)

            if betterWidth < rect.size.width {
                let difference : CGFloat = rect.size.width - betterWidth
                newRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x + difference/2, y: rect.origin.y, width: betterWidth, height: rect.size.height)
            }
        }
    }

    super.drawText(in: newRect)
}
```

Comment: I don't think textAlignment is important.  This also worked on .left

Answer (score 0):

There is no support built in for what you need. You will need to do your own calculations using `NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`. You will need to loop through various sizes to find the best width to get two filled lines. Then use that width to size the `UILabel`.

Comment: That's what I thought.. Would you mind giving a few lines of code to show how you would solve this ? I'm not 100% sure how you suggest I use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`..

Answer (score -1):

If you are using auto layout, [UILabel's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth) `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property may be of use to you.

Comment: Mmm.. Thanks, but I'm really not sure that it would help.. I don't use autolayout (I know, it's bad) but even if I were, as I commented on my question, I don't know beforehand what amount of text will be set to the label, so I don't know what the preferredMaxLayoutWidth would be..